# Linking Library that uses MPI, I don't, what happens behind the hood

Tags: mpi, dynamic-linking, openmpi

I am linking against a library that is built with OpenMPI support for internal processes.

My application is being built with no MPI support, and I link against this library. I have no idea what is happening behind the hood with regards to mpi. If library A loads/calls functions from openmpi, does this mean I can run my application with runmpi to get the library processes to distribute themselves? If I decide to make the application MPI aware and want to use mpich2 instead of OpenMPI or if I want to use Library B that is linked against mpich instead of openmpi, will the library and my application behave themselves in their individual message spaces? Is it typical to force application developers to explicitly link an mpi implementation to use an mpi-enabled library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal practice is that the developer ultimately compiles and links everything against a single MPI implementation. Where there are libraries depending on MPI, I typically see builds of the library for each available MPI implementation on a system. If you could somehow manage to link in two MPI implementations, and come up with their separate `MPI_Init` and `MPI_COMM_WORLD` definitions to use in the separate pieces of code, it might even work. That would be really tenuous, though. Don't do it.

As for your earlier question, it is almost possible to have an application call into a library using MPI and just have it do the right thing. First, the code will have to call `MPI_Init` *somewhere*. whether that's in the client or wholly encapsulated in the library may vary. The library will have to know what *MPI communicator* it's supposed to use; typically the client code would pass one in. Finally, the client code will have to take account of the fact that it will run on all MPI processes, not just one of them. So if it does any IO or other computation that should only happen in one process, then you'll need to set conditions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Another question, although kind of subjective. If the application doesn't use MPI, but the library passes around MPI datatypes internally, is it reasonable to ask the developer to make sure that the library headers import the right mpi.h implementation *and* link against the right mpi even though we do not need that at all (so much extra linking when it should just be loaded by the library object and handled in source and not by the header).I'm looking for some fuel for bug report/change request.

Comment: if the library is using MPI at all, compiling and linking against the same MPI implementation for the whole application really is necessary. This is just how it works in that space. As someone who writes code similar to libraries that use MPI, I would reject such a bug report/change request as invalid and not a worthwhile use of my effort